# What does _ (Underscore) mean in this context in Prolog Amzi

Tags: prolog, amzi-prolog

I have been trying to learn some Prolog Amzi. This is an example question and can't quite wrap my head around this question.

This is the code.

```
/* Facts */
parent(mary,tom).
parent(john,tom).
parent(mary,alice).
parent(john,alice).
sex(mary, female).
sex(john, male).
sex(tom, male).
sex(alice, female).
/* Rules */
mother(X):-
 sex(X,female),
 parent(X,_).
father(X):-
 sex(X, male),
 parent(X,_).
sibling(X,Y):-
 parent(M,X),
 sex(M,female),
 parent(F,X),
 sex(F,male),
 parent(M,Y),
 parent(F,Y).
sibling1(X,Y):-
 parent(M,X),
 sex(M,female),
 parent(F,X),
 sex(F,male),
 parent(M,Y),
 parent(F,Y),
 X \= Y.
go:-
 nl, nl,
 write('Hello there .....'), nl,
 write('Testing on Prolog2.'), nl,
 write('End Job'), n1.
```

The question asks what the function of the underscore in the rules mother(X) and father(X) is with examples of output.

I don't seem to understand what the underscore means in this context and what it means by example output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any context, an **anonymous variable** (denoted by `_`) represents an argument whose specific value is irrelevant.

For example, the rule `mother(X) :- sex(X, female), parent(X, _).` states that for *X* to be a *mother*, *X* must be *female* and also be the *parent* of someone (whose name is irrelevant and must represented by an anonymous variable).

The anonymous variable (`_`) does not bind to values, and multiple occurrences of it do not imply equal values.

Consider, for example, the following facts:

```
parent(mary, tom).
parent(mary, alice).
parent(john, tom).
parent(john, alice).
```

To find out who Mary's children are, you can ask:

```
?- parent(mary, Who).
Who = tom ;
Who = alice.
```

To find out whether Mary is someone's parent, you can ask:

```
?- parent(mary, _).
true .
```

To find out whether there is someone who is someone else's parent, you can ask:

```
?- parent(_, _).
true .
```

To find out whether there are people who are their own parents, you can ask:

```
?- parent(X, X).
false.
```

Comment: I also am a bit confused on what the difference between rule sibling and sibling1 is and why their outputs are different. Focusing on the \=.

Comment: The condition `X \= Y` ensures that a person is not considered to be his own sibling.